# find log files older than 30 days period

Tags: linux, find

I'm working on a script to find files older than 30 days in a given folder. Based on requirement i have to delete only files with extension *.log* or *.out* and skip sub directories.

The below command is returning all the .log* files that are modified 30 days ago. However it is returning all the .out files even the recent ones. is there something wrong in the below code?

```
    find -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -name "*.log*" -o -name "*.out*"
```

could you let me know what is wrong in the above statement

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f \( -name "*.log*" -o -name "*.out*" \)
```

The problem was that `find` binds logical-and tighter than logical-or.  The parens counteract that.

Without the parens, `find` is looking for files that match *either* (a) `-mtime +30 -type f -name "*.log*"` *or* (b) `-name "*.out*"`.

With the parens, `find` is looking for files that (a) match `-mtime +30 -type f` *and* (b) match either `-name "*.log*"` or `-name "*.out*"`.